# Django Migration is not applying the migration changes

Tags: django

Using django 1.7.7 I want to use django's migration to add or remove a field.
so I modified model.py and ran

```
python manage.py makemigrations myproj
Migrations for 'myproj':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Interp
    - Create model InterpVersion

python manage.py migrate myproj
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: myproj
Running migrations:
  Applying myproj.0001_initial... FAKED

python manage.py runserver
```

Then checked the admin page, it is not updated.
Then I tried removing the migration folder and tried again; the migrate command says there are no migrations to apply.

How can I do the migration?
Note: I want to use the new technique using django's migration not the old south approach.

Comment: Is myproj added to the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Seems strange that it would give you a `0001_initial` for models that have previously been created. Did you update from an older Django version?

Comment: No. Just a clean start with django 1.7.7.

Comment: Go to you migration folder, delete `0001_initial.py` file then run `python manage.py makemigrations myproj` then run `python manage.py migrate`. This is your initial migration for the app `myproj`. So try this and let us know the result.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Deleting the migration directory is never a good idea, because Django then loses track of which migration has been applied and which not (and once an app is deployed somewhere it can become quite difficult to get things back in sync).

> **Disclaimer**: whenever things like that occur it is best to backup the database if it contains anything valuable. If in early development it is not necessary, but once things on the backend get out of sync there is a chance of things getting worse. :-)

---

To recover, you could try resetting your models ***to match exactly what they were before you have added/removed the fields***. Then you can run

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations myproj
```

which will lead to an initial migration (`0001_initial...`). Then you can tell Django to fake that migration, which means to tell it to set its internal counter to this `0001_initial`:

With Django 1.7:

```
$ python manage.py migrate myproj
```

With Django >= 1.8:

```
$ python manage.py migrate myproj --fake-initial
```

Now, try to change your model and run `makemigrations` again. It should now create a `0002_foobar` migration that you could run as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Not deleting the folder is important to know. I got it working, but the --fake-initial option is not recognized. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, my bad. `--fake-initial` was added in Django 1.8. From the docs: "The --fake-initial flag was added to migrate; previously, initial migrations were always automatically fake-applied if existing tables were detected."

Comment: Updated the answer to be more precise on that.

Answer (score 42):

**Make sure that the `migrations/` folder contains a `__init__.py` file**

Lost half an hour over that.

Comment: this saved me half an hour for sure

Comment: Wowzy. Why Django. Why world :(

Comment: I would have never come up with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

In my case, the migrations were not being reflected in mysql database. I manually removed the row of 'myapp'(in your case 'myproj') from the table 'django_migrations' in mysql database and ran the same commands again for migration.

Comment: wanted to upvote and let people know that this solved my problem! Keep it in mind if nothing else owrked.

Answer (score 11):

Most of the above solutions would help in the issue, however, I wanted to point out another possible (albeit rare) possibility that the `allow_migrate` method of database router may be returning `False` when it should have returned `None`.

Django has a setting [`DATABASE_ROUTERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#database-routers) which will be used to determine which database to use when performing a database query.

From the docs:

> if you want to implement more interesting database allocation behaviors, you can define and install your own database routers.

A database router class implements up to four methods:

- db_for_read(model, **hints)
- db_for_write(model, **hints)
- allow_relation(obj1, obj2, **hints)
- allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints)

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate):

> allow_migrate(db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints)
>
> Determine if the migration operation is allowed to run on the database with alias db. Return True if the operation should run, False if it shouldn’t run, or None if the router has no opinion.

It is possible that one of the database routers in sequence is returning **False** for the migration that you're trying to run, in which case the particular operation will not be run.

Comment: I had to look through like ten overflow answers to find this. I renamed my app and got it one-off and this bit me.

Answer (score 6):

I find Django migrations a bit of a mystery, and tend to prefer external tools (liquibase, for example).

However, I just ran into this "No migrations to apply" problem as well. I also tried removing the `migrations` folder, which doesn't help.

If you've already removed the `migrations` folder, here's an approach that worked for me.

First, generate the new "clean" migrations:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations foo
Migrations for 'foo':
  dashboard/foo/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Foo
    - Create model Bar
```

Then look at the SQL and see if it looks reasonable:

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate foo 0001
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Foo
--
CREATE TABLE "foo" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, ... "created_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX "..." ON "foo" (...);
COMMIT;
```

Then apply execute that same SQL on your database.

I'm using Postgres but it will be similar for other engines.

One way is to write the content to a file:

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate foo 0001 > foo.sql
$ psql dbname username < foo.sql
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
COMMIT
```

Another is pipe the SQL directly:

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate foo 0001 | psql dbname username
```

Or copy and paste it, etc.

Comment: I spent two days searching for this solution. I wish I could upvote multiple times, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, make sure that in models.py, you have `managed = True` in each table's meta

Answer (score 3):

```
pip install django-extensions
```

and add this in the install app of `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_extensions'
]
```

Then run

```
python ./manage.py reset_db
```

Then run migrations again

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Now, run migrations for your installed apps

```
python manage.py makemigrations your_app_name
python manage.py migrtate your_app_name
```

Done! See Your Database...

Answer (score 2):

If you've deleted all migration files and tables, then do these steps:

1. python manage.py makemigrations appname
2. python manage.py migrate appname
3. delete rows of that app from django_migrations table
4. python manage.py migrate appname --fake-initial.
   It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your db

- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

and see your data base this is working :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue when trying to migrate my models after creating it in `models.py`. The problem was that I had not registered the app name in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`. The app name in my case was "core":

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core'
]
```

After adding it to `INSTALLED_APPS`, the migrations worked like usual:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrew E above but with a few changes especially where you haven't deleted the migrations folder in your quest to resolve the issue

1 - In your intact migration folder just examine the 000*.py files counting from the highest down to initial.py till you find the one where your Model is defined, say 0002_entry.py

2 - python manage.py sqlmigrate app-name 0002 > 0002_sql.txt to capture the SQL commands

3 - Edit this file to ensure there are no hard CR/LFs and the ALTER, CREATE INDEX commands are each on own single line

4 - Log into your DB (I have Postgres) and run these commands

Answer (score 0):

In Database delete row **`myproj`** from the table **`django_migrations`**.
Delete all migration files in the migrations folder.
Then run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem even when i had the migrations folder.
So I tried tricking the migrations to run the initial migration again.
I altered a field in my model and then  did a `python manage.py makemigrations` to create a new migration.
Then copied the operations list in the 0001_initial.py and pasted it above the newly created migration operation started with 0002_....py
This is the final code I used:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Operator',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('deactive', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('operator', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='operator', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Teams',
            fields=[
                ('owner', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='teams_owner', serialize=False, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('operators', models.ManyToManyField(related_name='teams_opearators', through='teams.Operator', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='operator',
            name='team',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='team', to='teams.teams'),
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='operator',
            name='deactive',
        ),
    ]
```

Don't forget to do the `python manage.py migrate` to apply the migration.
Worked fine for me. Hope it helps :)